# Do you know book's name under the topic of anti corrosion materials and binders?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

I need book's name talking about anti-corrosion materials or binders to complete my graduation project

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not a reference request service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although closed ; I will recommend Corrosion Handbook , Ulhig, pub. John Wiley & sons , 1948. Old , but if one understood everything in this one book you would be an expert today.